# Scientific number format in R

Tags: r, format, numbers

Considering the code below.

```
x <- c(3423, 123412121, 4567121)
format(x, scientific = TRUE)

[1] "3.423000e+03" "1.234121e+08" "4.567121e+06"
```

The results are using different exponential each time like e+03, e+08, e+06.

Is there a way to get the results with a fixed exponential ? Like say all output should be in e+03 ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

With options(scipen=999) you get the full number without e+03 and so on. Maybe there is a way with options(scipen=...)

Comment: Thanks, I want the output with exponential like e+03, but fixed not variable.